# Related products

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

In my model I have a `ManyToManyField` to select related products. I'm wondering what would be the best way to bring these into my view and render them in my template.

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(ProductCategory)
    featured_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_dir)
    about_this_product = models.TextField()
    standard_features = models.TextField(null=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    related_models = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True, null=True)
    model_slug = AutoSlugField(null=True, default=None,
                         unique=True, populate_from='title')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Products"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
def model_detail_view(request, category_slug, model_slug):
    product_model = get_object_or_404(Product, model_slug=model_slug) 
    context = {
        "title": "Products | %s" % product_model.title,
        "product": product_model,
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name='main/product_model_detail.html', context=context)
```

Comment: `{% for related in myproduct.related_models.all %}`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.prefetch_related(..)` just like you do on any one-to-many relation in the view:

```
def my_view(request):
    products = Product.objects.prefetch_related('related_models')
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'products': products})
```

Then in the template, you can iterate over the `.related_models` collection:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {{ product.title }}
    related:
    {% for rel in product.related_models.all %}
        {{ rel.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I updated my question with my views.py Your code works but I'm trying to show the related products on the product detail page. I tried using prefetch_related on my `get_object_or_404` but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @GTA.sprx: for a single object, you should not `.prefetch_related`, since then there is no performance gain at all. Only for a set of (usually at least) two objects.